# How to copy certain files from the same directory to another dirctory in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, command

I am fairly new here and didn't use a lot of Windows Command Prompt's advanced function. So bear with me...

Currently, I have a folder containing a lot of image files. The example file name is like `20130611.084021.c123.tif`, which means `YrMoDy.HrMinSec.cameraIDs.tif`.

So I want to copy all of the files have the same following information in their file names to another folder: `20130611.08xxxx.c1xx.tif`.

How can I do this in Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
copy 20130611.08*.c1*.tif <destination folder>
```

Comment: That's easy! Thanks Nolan!!